# Bluetooth serial is busy

Tags: bluetooth

My Bluetooth Serial seems to always be busy.

- `lsof /dev/tty.BluetoothModem` yields nothing.
- `sudo chmod 777 /var/lock` seemed to have no effect.
- `screen /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem`  tells me it's busy.

I rebooted.  I'm using Mountain Lion.  How can I possibly debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem` isn't the device that I want. I went into the Bluetooth preference pane and selected my device, clicked "Advanced", and added a new software serial device associated with it.  I can connect to that one just fine.